# WSO2-IS Recover Password with Mail - IdentityRecoveryServerException

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've configured an user and tried to use Recover Password by Mail from WSO2-IS following this documentation:

[Password Recovery by Mail](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/password-recovery/#password-recovery)

But when I enter with my email and click on **Submit** on MyAccount it shows an error:

[image]

And log shows:

```
[2022-08-05 18:32:26,931] [4afcc623-e283-45b7-b306-38add4fe3cb9] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery.endpoint.impl.RecoverPasswordApiServiceImpl} - 
Error occurred in the server while performing the task. org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery.IdentityRecoveryServerException: 
Configured callback URL does not match with the provided callback URL: https://localhost:9444/authenticationendpoint/login.do%3Fclient_id=MY_ACCOUNT&code_challenge=Me2BTFFVJh5zLFgPjSkMqENroq2A_vE9IQOc6b7cjIk
&code_challenge_method=S256&commonAuthCallerPath=/oauth2/authorize&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&redirect_uri=https://localhost:9444/myaccount/login&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code
&scope=SYSTEM+openid&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=ddd9d751-20e4-4061-bb7b-d166318ceb85&relyingParty=MY_ACCOUNT&type=oidc&sp=My+Account&isSaaSApp=true&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL in the request.
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: in your flow there's a mismatch between the expected call back URL where your redirect the user and the allowed URL configured in identity server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a validation happening for the callback URL coming in the request. You can pre configure it from the WSO2 IS management console resident IDP section as below, So you can preconfigure a regex pattern that matches the callback URL. If not use the wildcard regex pattern  .*   to allow any URL as below.

[image]

Comment: How can I redirect user to a specific login page after user click on "Submit"?